# Create batch script to edit host file by network connection

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, network-programming

I want to use this batch script to add new entries into my host file automatically by using windows batch.

I want to edit host file only when i m in office. I want to say like that:
if(network name=='OfficeWifi') do changes...

```
@echo off

set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
// if(network name=='OfficeWifi')
echo 81.155.145.48 ns1.intranet.de >> %hostspath%

exit
```

thx for your help

Comment: This will add the entry multiple times if you run it multiple times. You also want to _remove_ the entry when not at that network. You don't want to script this yourself. Check http://superuser.com/questions/663183/change-hosts-file-based-on-connection-windows for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the network name (SSID) of the currently connected wireless network using the following batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr /r "^....SSID"' ) do @echo %%a
```

So your batch file would look like:

```
@echo off
set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr /r "^....SSID"' ) do (
  if "%%a"=="OfficeWifi" echo 81.155.145.48 ns1.intranet.de >> %hostspath%
)
exit
```

---

Sources [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), [NETSH (Network Shell)](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)

Answer (score 1):

to make it simple you could just add :

```
@echo off

set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
ping "name of office DC" 
if errorlevel 1 quit    
if not errorlevel 1 echo 81.155.145.48 ns1.intranet.de >> %hostspath%
```

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is just have the script copy 1 of 2 different versions of the hostsfile depending on if error level is 1 or not. this saves you the trouble of format issues within the hostfile and need to clear it after.