# Create batch script to change network settings by current network connection

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, networking

I want to use a batch script which:

- changes my network settings to a static ip when I'm at home
- changes my network settings to dhcp when I'm not at home

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798355/create-batch-script-to-edit-host-file-by-network-connection/30801743#30801743) that you can check the network name by using

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr /r "^....SSID"' ) do @echo %%a
```

So if I want to create a batch script like that would it look something like this?

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr /r "^....SSID"' ) do (
    if "%%a"=="My_Cool_Home_Network" 
        netsh interface ip set address "NetworkAdapter" static 192.168.2.33 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.1
        netsh interface ip set dns "NetworkAdapter" static 192.168.2.1
    else
        netsh interface ip set address "NetworkAdapter" dhcp
        netsh interface ip set dns "NetworkAdapter" dhcp
)
```

Comment: You missed parenthesis at your `if`/`else` construct: `if "%%a"=="My_Cool_Home_Network" (` -- `netsh [...]` -- `) else (` -- `netsh [...]` -- `)` --- type `if /?` in command prompt for details...

Comment: Even with the parenthesis it doesn't work :(

Comment: My intention was just to fix the `if`/`else` syntax; I'm afraid I cannot help you with the `netsh` command...

Comment: Why not just configure your router at home to assign your device a static lease / IP reservation?  Most can assign a pre-defined IP address outside the DHCP scope based on the device's MAC address.  That's how I assign IPs in my house, anyway.  That way if your significant other borrows your laptop and doesn't trigger the script, then he/she won't waste 30 minutes of the wifi provider's time troubleshooting the inability to access the net despite the successful connection.

Comment: Could you post the updated code? I think I might have an idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: @rojo This is pretty much the easiest solution for my problem! Thank you very much. It worked for me